# multiple start day on calendar event and Not showing Events on full-calendar

Tags: laravel, fullcalendar

i'm looking for same event for multiple days in full-calendar

**Here is sample JSON data :**

```
{
    "JSON": [{
        "title": "sdc",
        "start": ["18-03-2020", "25-03-2020"],
        "end": ["18-03-2020", "25-03-2020"],
        "events_id": 30,
        "event_description": "xzcv"
    }]
}
```

**is it possible start date as multiple  date with single name event**
The full-calendar not showing a start date more then one array,

Comment: It sounds like you want recurring events. Please read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/recurring-events and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/rrule-plugin

Comment: can you explain it more ...actually i dont get idea through that docs

Comment: Recurring events is the way you define an event which happens on multiple dates, with a repeating pattern (e.g. once each week, or twice each month, something like that). However, if your repeating events do not have a regular pattern, then you simply must create two event objects in your JSON. (You can still give them the same `groupId`, to link them together, fullCalendar will accept that (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing).)